# Caching NGINX proxy returning MISS

Tags: nginx, caching

I currently have the configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:180m inactive=60m max_size=700m;
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

...

server_name example.com
location / {
    proxy_cache my_zone;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$uri";
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 100d;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

But when accessing the server I always seem get `x-proxy-cache: MISS`:

```
$ curl -I https://example.com
```

How come?

Comment: probably it is a silly question.. but did you restart nginx..?

this documentation can be handy as well: https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-caching

Comment: Not silly but yes I did! I think it is something todo with the url not having an extension?

Comment: my .css/.js etc... files cache perfectly.